# I need to diagnose an issue with my code, I am getting an error while trying to run a discord notification program I wrote

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Notification() {
    if (queueData.place <= "500") {
        msg.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 3447003,
                author: {
                    name: client.user.username,
                    icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
                },
                title: "2bored2wait discord bridge",
                //url: "http://google.com",
                description: "Your being pinged",
                fields: [{
                        name: "Position",
                        value: `@everyone You're below position **${queueData.place}**.`
                    },
                    {
                        name: "ETA",
                        value: `Estimated time until login: **${queueData.ETA}**`
                    }
                ],
                timestamp: new Date(),
                footer: {
                    icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                    text: "Author: Surprisejedi"
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am using this code to make a system that notifies me on discord since this is a discord bot. When I am below position 30 I use 500 as a placeholder.

Pastebin of the file for the discord controlled bot: https://pastebin.com/ziFE7ZXT
My error is:

````
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)[39m
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47[39m" ```
````

Comment: In the pastebin, you omitted a `}` at the very end of the function declaration.

Comment: Dude, why are you so in-specific. Posting your code like that is saying, here take my work and do it for me. Have you tried to solve the issue at all? if so please explain what you have done, if not then please try first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "escape" single quote character in `everyone You\'re` in fields array.